# Casting Flame Strike or Ice Storm in a cave/dungeon

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

So, one of my players who plays a druid wanted to cast "Flame Strike" and "Ice Storm" in a dungeon. In the german version of the rule books, those spells both state that the Ice/Fire comes **from the sky**. We assumed that this makes the spells impossible to be cast inside, but now, as I read up on it, the spells actually state nothing of that in the english versions.

Is this just due to a poor choice of translation, and the spells can actually be cast inside? I just wanted to make sure, as I am still a bit irritated by the german descriptions.

For those of you that understand german:

**Flame Strike (Flammenschlag)**

> Dieser Zauber erschafft eine Säule göttlichen Feuers, die aus dem Himmel niederfährt.

**Ice Storm (Eissturm)**

> Große, magische Hagelkörner regnen vom Himmel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## A spell says if limits to its casting exist

A creature can cast [*flame strike*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/flame-strike) and [*ice storm*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/ice-storm) indoors as easily as he can cast [*fireball*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fireball) and [*cone of cold*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/cone-of-cold).

You can compare this to [*call lighting*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/call-lightning), which says specifically

> This spell functions indoors or underground but not underwater.

### The areas make the spells different

The difference between the *ice storm* and *flame strike* spells and a simple *fireball* or *cone of cold* is their areas. The *strike* and *storm* are cylinders, which is a different kind of area than the more common cones and bursts. If you cast a spell with an area of a [cylinder](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Aiming-a-Spell)

> you select the spell's point of origin. This point is the center of a horizontal circle, and the spell shoots down from the circle, filling a cylinder. A cylinder-shaped spell ignores any obstructions within its area.

So you can totally pick the roof over your head or a point in space 5 ft. above the target area.